# Should a Sql Server be accessible through the service's virtual network name?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

In a working SQL-Server failover cluster environment I can open a SQL-Server connection using the configured service's IP address independantly of the current node it is on. I wonder if the assigned virtual network name should allow to be used as well to connect? Actually it's not possible to use it.

So instead of `10.20.30.40\instance1` should I be able to connect using `sqlnetwork01\instance1` as well? Do I face a configuration mistake if I can't or do I have a misunderstanding of the concepts?

Edit:
`sqlnetwork01\instance1` is accessible from the same domain, my mistake was to try from a different one where it does not answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given CLUSTER_1, with NODE_1 and NODE_2, and virtual network VNN_1 with IP_1, these will work:

- VNN_1\INSTANCE
- IP_1\INSTANCE

These will not work:

- CLUSTER_1\INSTANCE
- NODE_1\INSTANCE
- NODE_2\INSTANCE

If you are unable to connect using VNN_1\INSTANCE then, can you ping it, and what does it resolve to? Is it configured for a single IP (i.e. not multi-subnet)?